# Inside the app section, is it possible to change the size of the icons in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? (Help requested)

Tags: unity

I am trying to change the icon size inside app section but I am unable to find a way to do this. I am attaching a picture to make myself clear on what I am trying to do.
[image]

In this image, you can see the icons appear so small. It only gives a feel of android screen. If we want to increase these icon sizes, how can we do this? (I am specifically referring to these icons only, because for other icons on desktop, and dock, there are ways available but not for these icons inside the app section.) If someone knows something about how can we do this, please guide me, I will follow. It will be marvellous if some slider like mechanism is available to do this. :D

My goal is to have icon size ***minimum*** to as below:
[image]

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Whats the gnome-shell version? `gnome-shell --version` are you using dash-to-panel extension??

Comment: GNOME Shell 3.36.7 Thanks. :)

Comment: When you disable dash to panel extension is there any improvement in size??

Comment: I have not used this extension named dash to panel. Without it size is what is in the picture. Now after you mentioned I tried dash to panel, it makes my superkey (dock) disappear, so I just disable it.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Wow!! This dash to panel is quite good. Enabling it has increased the size for me!! The size of icons have increased inside the app section. Thanks a million friend. :)

Comment: There are two things that could further needs to solve in this same regard so I am not posting it new question. 1. When I did the above, I only see 9 icons in "All" in one row and 10 apps in "Frequent" in one row?! I also use one useful extension named more more columns in application view. 2. The icons size can still be increased for better aesthetics but I do not know how to do that.